# Calling a subset of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

```
x_train = train['date_x','activity_category','char_1_x','char_2_x','char_3_x','char_4_x','char_5_x','char_6_x',
'char_7_x','char_8_x','char_9_x','char_10_x',.........,'char_27','char_29','char_30','char_31','char_32','char_33',
'char_34','char_35','char_36','char_37','char_38']
y = y_train
x_test = test['date_x','activity_category','char_1_x','char_2_x','char_3_x','char_4_x','char_5_x','char_6_x',
'char_7_x','char_8_x','char_9_x','char_10_x','char_1_y','group_1','char_1_y','char_2_y','char_3_y', 'char_4_y','char_5_y','char_6_y','char_7_y',
'char_8_y','char_9-y','char_10_y', ...........,'char_29','char_30','char_31','char_32','char_33',
'char_34','char_35','char_36','char_37','char_38']

train.iloc([0:17,19:38])
```

After trying to slice columns with `train([0:17,19:38)]`, I resorted to data entry of all column names. A pretty cumbersome way of doing this, but I am only getting what I call with `19:38`. I am getting Key error message for doing it the first way, by calling the column names.

Comment: If `pandas` behaves anything like `numpy`, you should be able to use `numpy.r_[0:17,19:38]` to turn those slices into a fancy index array.

Comment: Even better: `pandas.np.r_[0:17,19:38]`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @AndrasDeak
Consider the `pd.DataFrame` `train`

```
train = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000).reshape(-1, 20))
```

Then use the suggestion like this

```
train.iloc[np.r_[0:17, 19:38]]
```